# Why did "chown" and "chgrp" changed permissions of a directory? It is not a "chmod"!

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown, file-ownership, chgrp

Everything was good on my website. Then I ran this:

```
root@[domain] [/home/[username]/public_html/[foldername]]# chown jaimemontoya -R webroot/
root@[domain] [/home/[username]/public_html/[foldername]]# chgrp jaimemontoya -R webroot/
```

What I was trying to do with the above was to change ownership from `root` to `jaimemontoya` for the `webroot` directory, and do it recursively. The result was that PERMISSIONS of `webroot` were changed from `drwxr-xr-x` to `drwxr-x---`. As a result, my entire website was down with the following error when visiting the home page:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /[foldername]/webroot/[location-name] on this
>   server. Server unable to read htaccess file, denying access to be safe
>
> Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to
>   use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I fixed it by modifying permissions for the `webroot` directory, changing it from `drwxr-x---` to `drwxr-xr-x`, since originally I was using `drwxr-xr-x`.

Bottom line: Why did using `chown jaimemontoya -R webroot/` and `chgrp jaimemontoya -R webroot/` changed PERMISSIONS of the `webroot` directory? It should have only changed OWNERSHIP, NOT PERMISSIONS. It was my understanding that if you needed to change PERMISSIONS you would need to use `chmod`, and I never used that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned it in the question, I fixed it by modifying permissions of the `webroot` directory, changing it from `drwxr-x---` to `drwxr-xr-x`. Of course I asked this question because I am trying to understand WHY the problem happened. Nonetheless, I know the solution and that is the most important thing.